# codeigniter update data from excel file (Array to string conversion)

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I'm try to update data in oracle table from excel file (.xlsx) use CodeIgniter. I've already uploaded the excel file but when I try to update the data I get the following error message:

```
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: database/DB_driver.php
Line Number: 1524
Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\web_excel_ci_test\application\models\RoadmapModel.php
Line: 84
Function: update

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\web_excel_ci_test\application\controllers\Roadmap.php
Line: 209
Function: update_data
```

Controller:

```
    function update(){
    $this->load->library('session');
    $fileName = $this->session->flashdata('fileName');
    $fileName2 = $this->session->flashdata('fileName2');

    include APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
    $excelreader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
    $loadexcel = $excelreader->load('excel/'.$fileName);
    $sheet = $loadexcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true ,true);

    $data = [];     
    $numrow = 1;
    foreach($sheet as $row){
        if($numrow > 1){
            array_push($data, [
                'YEAR'=>$row['A'], 
                'PROVINCEID'=>$row['B'], 
                'PROVINCE'=>$row['C'], 
                'PLAN_A'=>$row['D'], 
                'ACTUAL_A'=>$row['E'],

            ]); 
        }
        $numrow++; 
    }
    $year = $this->input->post('YEAR');
    $this->RoadmapModel->update_data($year, $fileName2, $data);
    redirect("Roadmap");
}
```

Model:

```
function update_data($year, $fileName2, $data){
    for ($i=0; $i < count($year) ; $i++) {
        $this->db->where('YEAR', $year[$i]);
        $this->db->update($fileName2, $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `print_r($data);` before `$this->db->update($fileName2, $data);` ... the error is pretty self-explanatory you are trying to convert an array to a string

Answer (score 0):

i think your $data is a multidimentional array, try to use

`$this->db->update_batch`

to process batch update. You can also look [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update#updating-data) to for more options.